# External Promethues unable to scrape kubernetes metrics: context deadline exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I setup a promtheus server outside kubernetes cluster. My configuration has 2 scrape jobs for kubernetes-apiservers and kubernetes-nodes metrics.
Target for kubernetes-apiservers endpoint is up, but with kubernetes-nodes, it shows error with  "context deadline exceeded" .Please have look and give me advice.

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 2m
  scrape_timeout: 30s
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus_master'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
                
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
    - role: endpoints
      kubeconfig_file: /etc/prometheus/dev-zznty9y19-kubeconfig
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
      ca_file: /etc/prometheus/ca.crt
    authorization:
#     bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/dev-zznty9y19-kubeconfig
      credentials_file: /etc/prometheus/token
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
        action: keep
        regex: default;kubernetes;https
  - job_name: 'kubernetes-nodes'
    kubernetes_sd_configs:            
    - role: node
#      api_server: https://172.16.21.31
      kubeconfig_file: /etc/prometheus/dev-zznty9y19-kubeconfig
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
      ca_file: /etc/prometheus/ca.crt
    authorization:
      credentials_file: /etc/prometheus/token          
    relabel_configs:
    - action: labelmap
      regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: 172.16.21.31:443
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
      regex: (.+)
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics
```

[prometheus target error kubernetes-nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qozrW.png)
Thanks

Comment: where did you get the credentials_file token value from?